# How to show that a function in $L_2$ space is uniformly bounded in the "truncated norm"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $$L_2[0, \infty) = \left\{f: \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}^n \mid \int_0^\infty f(t)^Tf(t) \, dt< \infty \right\}$$

Define the truncated norm as

$$\|f\|_K = \sqrt{\int_0^K f(t)^Tf(t) \, dt}$$ with $K \geq 0$

Is it true that any $f \in L_2$ will be uniformly bounded in the truncated norm?

i.e. $\exists \beta$ s.t. $\|f\|_K \leq \beta \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}_+$

Comment: I'm confused, what exactly is $f(t)^T$?  And is $\left\|f\right\|_K$ well defined? You are taking a square root of something that could be negative? And why do you say $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}_+$ in the last line when $\left\|f\right\|_K$ does not depend on $t$?

Comment: $f$ is a degenerate matrix, so $f^T f=f^2$. However there is no $t$ in the norm...

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry $f: \mathbb{R}_{+} \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @Mathematician42 Sorry there were some typos...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want this $\forall K>0$, not all $t$. Since $f(t)^Tf(t)\geq0$, you can take $\beta=(\int_0^{\infty}f(t)^Tf(t)\,dt)^{1/2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Just note that $\|f\|_K^2=\int_0^K f(t)^Tf(t) \, dt\leq \int_0^\infty f(t)^Tf(t) \, dt$ for all $K$, since $f(t)^Tf(t)$ is always nonnegative.